i need to resive data external api and show user
i have one form for user , this form send code to external api and i need show user callback responce api this page and not ind plugin for this work (for show responce api current page for user )
i have tested ninja form - contact form7 - wp-getapi and 2 more form plugin not work
........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Please edit your question to more fully explain what you need. Include any relevant code snippets.

I'm not sure what you're saying exactly: that the external API call needs to be made directly by the client and not from the server ("ind plugin") ? That'll depend on the CORS settings of the external server. You'd probably do better making the call from server side code on your server.

And if showing the response is the issue do you want that to happen with or without a page reload on your site? That feels like it should be easy to do. Like Pat says, can you explain more about what you've tried and why it isn't working?

yeh i need show data api to current page and no reload page  , data api have json but form builder no option for send data to api and recived data and show to sucsess box
